# Bitmap color code change after scaledown

Tags: android, colors, bitmap

I have one image which have color code of #AAA28B (170R,162G,139B). Now let's say current image size is 1200x1200 now I want to make it scale down at 600x600 so i use below code and get resulted in bitmap but the problem is its bitmap color code change to #ABA38C, So it RGB values increase to plus one compare to original image color and become (171R,163G,140B) how to prevent this?.

See attach a screenshot where the first image if original loaded directly from android drawable and other it loads by using following code.

```
private void loadImage(int width, int height){

        Bitmap bitMapTest=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_test);

        Log.i("IMAGE","Image format is"+ bitMapTest.getConfig().name()+
                "Image size is"+ bitMapTest.hasAlpha() + "bitmap size is"+ bitMapTest.getHeight());


        Bitmap decodeBitmap=decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_test,width,height);
        Log.i("IMAGE","Image format is"+ decodeBitmap.getConfig().name()+
                "Image size is"+ decodeBitmap.hasAlpha() + "bitmap size is"+ decodeBitmap.getHeight());

         //adjust of alha deos not give me any help result remain same
        //decodeBitmap=adjustOpacity(decodeBitmap);

        mImgView.setImageBitmap(decodeBitmap);

    }

    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        options.inPreferredConfig= Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        options.inScaled=false;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 2;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```

Here is orginal image :-

[image: Here is solid color image which i need to scale down]

Comment: How can a bitmap have a color code? Pixels have color codes.

Comment: i have fully colors image , Let's me share that wait

Comment: `decodeBitmap=adjustOpacity(decodeBitmap);`. Please try without.

Comment: `I have one image which have color code `. Bitmap and images have no color code. Only pixels do. Please edit.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry for miss guide by color code , I have also try by removing `decodeBitmap=adjustOpacity(decodeBitmap);` but result it same

Comment: `Sorry for miss guide by color code `. If you feel sorry then edit your post as i asked you to do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like applying following code for scaledown working fine for the solid image like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF7JO.jpg).

```
Bitmap  decodeBitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(sourceBitmap,width,height,false/*Make sure filter is false*/);
```